# Why it can iterate child process?

Tags: linux, kernel

In Linux kernel Development ( 3rd Edition )

According to this book, this code can iterate each child process by this code:

(@ Chapter 3.2.6)

```
struct task_struct *task
struct list_head *list

list_for_each(list, &current->children) {
      task = list_entry ( list, struct task_struct, sibling);
}
```

What I don't understand, we should already got each child's task_struct pointer by

```
list_for_each(list, &current->children)
```

why we still need the second line:

```
task = list_entry ( list, struct task_struct, sibling);
```

Comment: `list` is a `struct list_head*`, not `struct task_struct*`.

Comment: list is a pointer of sibling in task_struct?

Comment: No, it's a pointer to a `list_head` structure. That contains a `task_struct`, and `sibling` is a member of that.

Comment: since list is a pointer of struct list_head which pointer to children, why the second line is not 'task = list_entry ( list, struct task_struct, children);'

Comment: Because the code wants to use the `sibling` member, not `children`. You can put whatever member you want there, to get a pointer to that member.

Comment: 'You can put whatever member you want there' -> Sorry, I don't understand this, list_entry is actually a container_of macro, we should pass the pointer's variable name (here I think it should pass children but here it passes sibling) to get the overall struct ( task_struct here)'s pointer, why pass sibling? the list pointer did not point to a sibling, why container_of marco can decode it?

Comment: `task_struct` has many members. The third argument to `list_entry` is the member you want a pointer to.

Comment: sorry, my understanding is the third argument to list_entry is the member name of first argument （here is 'list', and it is a pointer to children, not sibling ), I am still confused.